# How to show long running process in Android Activity?

Tags: android

I use to use hourglass cursor in other system, however there is no cursor image. I can't also show toast, since it can disappear before process finishes. SHould I pop a message box? Or there is something more Android specific?

Answer (score 1):

There is ProgressDialog. Works particularly well with AsyncTask.

Comment: I thought about it, although it is certain overhead for me, since I need just take attention user that system is working. Major delay is in establishing HTTP connection when invalid host specified and no actual progress here. Anyway I can show some fake progress. You gave me also idea to apply reasonably short timeout for IO read, so thank you.